# Onclick Javascript html loading, but visually small. Not sure what is going on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Onclick javascipt element loads external html into div, however it is constrained to a left floating 150x100px "box" with a vertical scroll bar.

I am assuming that I have to add information to specify the size when loading, but I am not sure on how to do this?

Onclick event within main file

```
<a href="#" class="homeButton" onclick="homeClick()">Home</a>
```

Javascript element in external file

```
function homeClick(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="include/home.html" ></object>';
}
```

Article div within main file

```
<article class="content" id="content"></article>
```

Article css in external file

```
article{
    clear:both;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Loaded content

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p></p>
    <h2>News Letter</h2>
    <p></p>
```

Comment: you can add a width and height in the CSS, this should be fine

Comment: When I add a set height and width in my css file for article, it does not change the results. I still end up with content in miniature window, unfortunately? Can I put this information somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Onclick javascipt element loads external html into div,

No. You have no `<div>` elements at all. You are putting an `<object>` into an `<article>`. The external HTML is loaded into the `<object>`. (Although why you don't just use an `<iframe>` which is better designed for that, I have no idea).

> I am assuming that I have to add information to specify the size when loading, but I am not sure on how to do this?

With the CSS `height` and `width` properties.

```
object {
    height: 500px;
    width: 27ex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Your description makes more sense with regards to the javascript function. However, adding css code specifying the article height and width in the css file does not change the resaults, nor does adding css for the content being processed. Do you have any recommendations for articles on Iframes?

Comment: @NavrajBains — "specifying the article height and width in the css file does not change the resaults" — It wouldn't do, because that doesn't touch the `<object>`. That's why I used `object {}` in my code example.

Comment: @NavrajBains — "Do you have any recommendations for articles on Iframes? " — https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe